# Dockerize several solution project into one dockerfile

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, dockerfile

There are several microservices in solution: api, auth, filtering. I'm wondering how to run them all in one dockerfile and docker-compose.

Here what i've done:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ShoppingCart.API/ShoppingCart.API.csproj", "ShoppingCart.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ShoppingCart.API/ShoppingCart.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ShoppingCart.API"
RUN dotnet build "ShoppingCart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ShoppingCart.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
    
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ShoppingCart.API.dll"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  localdev:
   name: localdev

services:
  api:
   container_name: api
   build: .
   depends_on: [ mssql ]
   ports:
    - "8080:80"
   networks:
    - localdev

  ordering:
   container_name: ordering

  mssql:
   image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
   container_name: mssql
   hostname: mssql
   environment:
    SA_PASSWORD: "fA0bD7rO3iE1mU0w"
    ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
   restart: unless-stopped
   networks:
    - localdev
   ports:
    - "1433:1433"
   expose:
    - 1433 

  rabbitmq:
   image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
   container_name: "rabbitmq"
   ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
```

So, API i could wrapped in docker. How to make it with others? For instance, in solution is ShoppingCart.Auth

Comment: You have to create `Dockerfile` for every microservice independently, and add  them into the `docker-compose` as services

Comment: @frank_lee Did i?! Okay, but how could docker-compose understand which of project i have to run!?

Comment: `which of project i have to run` => as I said, you have to create Dockerfile for every microservice independently, then docker-compose runs all the services together